# html tags in gettext hook get escaped

Tags: filters, html

Hy everyone!

[Here](https://www.cpu20.com/2017/wordpress-change-string-translations-without-plugin/) I found this code

```
function gb_change_cart_string($translated_text, $text, $domain) {
  translated_text = str_replace("original string", "modified string", $translated_text);
  return $translated_text; 
} 
add_filter('gettext', 'gb_change_cart_string', 100, 3);
```

to change a string in the template without using a plugin (I just need it for a couple of strings in the whole website, so I'd rather avoid using a plugin).

It works fine but I need to have a link in the modified text.
I tried this:

```
function gb_change_cart_string($translated_text, $text, $domain) {
  translated_text = str_replace("original string", "modified string with my <a href='https://website-i-want-to.link'>link</a>", $translated_text);
  return $translated_text; 
} 
add_filter('gettext', 'gb_change_cart_string', 100, 3);
```

but in the website I get the tag as text, as if the '<' and '>' were escaped.

Does anyone knows a way to avoid this and have the tag as a real html tag?

Thanks a lot in advance!

**Edit**: I also tried to use single quotes for the string that contains the tag.

Comment: It is not possible to answer this question without seeing the code that prints the text. If you need help with WooCommerce though you should ask in a WooCommerce forum or their support routes